# A question about the reflexive verb "faire" and the verb "payer"

Tags: pronoms-réfléchis

I can't understand a certain grammatical construction! Please explain to me who is the subject of the verb *payer* in the following sentence:

> nulle part on ne voit, disons-nous, que ce digne gentilhomme ait été accusé de se faire ***payer*** la coopération de ses séides".

Les trois mousquetaires - Alexandre Dumas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Payer", by itself, is not an immediate constituent in the clause where it is found; in other words it is not a verb in the clause; "faire payer" is a verb, or to be more precise, a verb form, since it is a combination of two verbs;  it is used pronominally. The meaning of this sort of combinations is explained on the site "[Parlez-vous French](https://parlez-vous-french.com/faire-signification-et-accord/)", at n° 6.

The subject of this verbal form is "gentilhomme". It is not a grammatical subject though; it is more properly called "*l'agent de l'infinif*". ("Gentihomme" is a word from the French of ages past: it is not used at all in modern French.) "Payer" has no subject in this sentence.

*A little more grammar*

"Faire" is considered to be a semi-auxiliary in French  (LBU § 821, 14th edition). (It's a verb a little like "get", in English).

> (LBU § 821)
> Il [le verbe « faire »] sert à former une périphrase factitive, de sens causatif : « Je ferai
> venir cet homme » signifie « je ferai en sorte qu'il viendra, je serai cause
> qu'il viendra » :
> • Et l'on FIT traverser tout Paris à ces femmes (HUGO, Châtim., V, 11).
> • Un coup de poing à la mâchoire la FIT lâcher prise (AYMÉ, Chemin des écoliers, p. 76).
> • Personne au monde ne le FERA changer d'avis (COCTEAU, Bacchus, III, 7)
> […]
> **Faire peut servir avec lui-même**
> • Certains hommes se réjouissent de FAIRE faire à leurs amis des choses
> qui leur sont désagréables (FLAUB., Éduc., II, 6).
> **À la forme pronominale**
> • Elle SE FAIT mourir à la tâche.
> • Je ME SUIS FAIT faire un nouveau costume.
> • L'homme qui SE FAIT photographier en académicien0- RENARD, Journal, 22 mars 1902).
> La valeur causative peut s'atténuer et la construction pronominale équivaloir
> à un passif :
> • Elle S'EST FAIT agresser, injurier, rattraper, violer, etc.
> • Notre maréchal [...]estun soldat distingué, lequel a pillé l'Espagne en SE FAISANT battre (CHAT. Mém., III, II, m, 3).
> Cela se réalise aussi quand l'infin. a un objet direct (le pronom réfléchi correspondant à un pronom personnel objet indirect dans la voix active) :
> • On lui a pris son sac → Elle S'EST FAIT prendre son sac.
> […]